# First order linear pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $xyu=C_{1}$ and $ x^{2}+ y^{2}-2u= C_{2}$, where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are arbitary constants be the first integrals of the pde 
$$ x(u+y^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}- y (u+x^{2})\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=(x^{2}-y^{2})u.$$ Then, the solution of the pde with $x+y=0$ and $u=1$ is given by..

Answer (score 1):

$$ x(u+y^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}- y (u+x^{2})\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= (x^{2}-y^{2})u.$$

Before to answer to the question, let us see where $xyu=C_{1}$ and $ x^{2}+ y^{2}-2u= C_{2}$ come from.

The characteristic equations are :
$$\frac{dx}{x(u+y^2)}=\frac{dx}{-y(u+x^2)}=\frac{du}{(x^{2}-y^{2})u}$$

The first characteristic curve is determined from a first combination of the above equations:

$\frac{dx}{x(u+y^2) }=\frac{dx}{ -y(u+x^2) }=\frac{du}{ (x^{2}-y^{2})u }= \frac{yudx+xudy+xydu}{yu(x(u+y^2))+xu(-y(u+x^2))+xy((x^{2}-y^{2})u)} =\frac{yudx+xudy+xydu}{ 0 }$

$yudx+xudy+xydu=0 \quad\to\quad d(xyu)=0 \quad\to\quad xyu=C_1$

The second characteristic curve is determined from a second combination of the above equations:

$\frac{dx}{x(u+y^2) }=\frac{dx}{ -y(u+x^2) }=\frac{du}{ (x^{2}-y^{2})u }= \frac{xdx+ydy-du}{x(x(u+y^2))+y(-y(u+x^2))-(x^{2}-y^{2})u} = \frac{xdx+ydy-du}{ 0 }$

$xdx+ydy-du=0 \quad\to\quad d(x^2+y^2-2u)=0 \quad\to\quad x^2+y^2-2u=C_2$

Thus, the general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form is :
$$\Phi\left( (xyu)\:,\: (x^2+y^2-2u)\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

Or, on another equivalent form, from solving the implicit equation for the second variable :

$x^2+y^2-2u=F(xyu)\quad $ where $F$ is any differentiable function.

The condition $u=1$ when $x+y=0$ (or $y=-x$) implies :

$x^2+(-x)^2-2(1)=F(x(-x)(1))\quad\to\quad 2x^2-2=F(-x^2)$

This determines $F(X)=-2X-2\quad\to\quad F(xyu)=-2xyu-2$

$$x^2+y^2-2u=-2xyu-2 $$
$$u=\frac{2+x^2+y^2}{2-2xy} $$